# I want to draw a multiline tree path with any visualization library supported in react like the below picture, which can have multiple root nodes

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, tree, vis.js, react-d3-graph

I want to draw a multiline tree path with any visualization library supported in react like the below picture, which can have multiple root nodes and one child can have more than one parent, but not able to find a perfect library fulfilling my results,

my research :

1. D3, in d3 tree heirarchy, multiple parents of a child is not supported, tried force simulation but ends up very complex result which did not help
2. visjs, works well but how to draw the links like the attached image, such links are available in default in d3 but when i try to customise the links it just gives me curve on one side. If anyone can guide me to draw such links then would be helpful, plus by defult the collaps of nodes is not supported in visjs
3. ForceGrpah, it has rendering challenges, very hard to maintain sequences of the nodes from left to right, it just scatter the graph randomly.

Please help me with a lib which can help me to overcome the problem.

reference graph below link

https://aeiqlmvzbqqtluvwxzosorcrysjncblt.share.thousandeyes.com/view/internet-insights/?roundId=1674631800&metric=interfaces&scenarioId=outageTraffic&filters=N4IgZglgNgLgpgJwM4gFygIYActQgYwxggHsA7AERIFsMIyAVDAczQG0Q8A3OEAGhDUCCEkhJgY-QcNHiY5PGV4DxkfMpCqCcAMwA2AKxSSAVxhQSJANZSkACwwI4WEvUkD4GakgB0Q-CJiEiAAugLYuAREpGQA8mYscADK%2BCRYvKgcAIIAYjkAogDCDPkUAPolSQxlsQBKZQCSAHJlhVkMWQAysQDioeFIZOxhIDAIGGBq8TCJKWkZ2XlFJeWV1XWNLW0d3X0hAL77QA

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.